# Facing Error in React To-Do App: "Cannot Read Properties of Undefined (Reading 'map')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm facing with an issue in my React to-do list application. An error message stating "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" when i click update todo button is disrupting my attempts to update the to-do list. The problem arises in the Todo.js file, where Redux is employed for state management. Despite extensive troubleshooting, I'm unsure why the error is occurring during the attempt to update to-dos on the screen.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`

[console.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMCqD.png)

As i am learning redux-toolkit please help me out this problem and your help will be appreciated.

Here is my completed code :

```
//todoSlice.js
import { createSlice, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  todos: [{ id: 1, text: "Hello World" }],
};

export const todoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todo",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTodo: (state, action) => {
      const todo = {
        id: nanoid(),
        text: action.payload,
      };
      state.todos.push(todo);
    },
    removeTodo: (state, action) => {
      state.todos = state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload);
    },
    updateTodo: (state, action) => {
      state.todos = state.todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...todo,
            text: action.payload.text,
          };
        }
        return todo;
      });
    },
  },
});

export const { addTodo, removeTodo, updateTodo } = todoSlice.actions;

export default todoSlice.reducer;

//store.js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import todoReducer from "../features/todo/todoSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: todoReducer,
});

//Todo.js

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { removeTodo } from "../features/todo/todoSlice";
import AddTodo from "./AddTodo";
import { useState } from "react";

function Todo() {
  const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todos);
  const [updatingTodo, setUpdatingTodo] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const updateTodoClick = (todo) => {
    setUpdatingTodo(todo);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <AddTodo onUpdateTodo={setUpdatingTodo} updatingTodo={updatingTodo} />
      <ul className="list-none" style={{ margin: "100px" }}>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li
            className="mt-4 flex justify-between items-center bg-zinc-800 px-4 py-2 rounded"
            key={todo.id}
          >
            <div className="text-white">{todo.text}</div>
            <div className="buttons">
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="text-white bg-indigo-500 mx-1 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-md"
                onClick={() => updateTodoClick(todo)}
              >
                Update
              </button>
              <button
                onClick={() => dispatch(removeTodo(todo.id))}
                className="text-white bg-red-500 border-0 py-1 px-4 focus:outline-none hover:bg-red-600 rounded text-md"
              >
                <svg
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  fill="none"
                  viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                  strokeWidth={1.5}
                  stroke="currentColor"
                  className="w-6 h-6"
                >
                  <path
                    strokeLinecap="round"
                    strokeLinejoin="round"
                    d="M14.74 9l-.346 9m-4.788 0L9.26 9m9.968-3.21c.342.052.682.107 1.022.166m-1.022-.165L18.16 19.673a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244 2.077H8.084a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244-2.077L4.772 5.79m14.456 0a48.108 48.108 0 00-3.478-.397m-12 .562c.34-.059.68-.114 1.022-.165m0 0a48.11 48.11 0 013.478-.397m7.5 0v-.916c0-1.18-.91-2.164-2.09-2.201a51.964 51.964 0 00-3.32 0c-1.18.037-2.09 1.022-2.09 2.201v.916m7.5 0a48.667 48.667 0 00-7.5 0"
                  />
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default Todo;

//Addtodo.js

import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo, updateTodo } from "../features/todo/todoSlice";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const AddTodo = ({ onUpdateTodo, updatingTodo }) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(updatingTodo ? updatingTodo.text : "");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const addTodoHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (updatingTodo) {
      dispatch(updateTodo({ id: updatingTodo, text: input }));
      onUpdateTodo(null);
    } else {
      dispatch(addTodo(input));
    }
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={addTodoHandler}
      className="space-x-3 mt-12 content-center"
      style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
    >
      <input
        type="text"
        className="bg-gray-800 rounded border border-gray-700 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-900 text-base outline-none text-gray-100 py-1 px-3 leading-8 transition-colors duration-200 ease-in-out"
        placeholder="Enter a Todo..."
        value={input}
        onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        type="submit"
        className="text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg"
      >
        {updatingTodo ? "Update Todo" : "Add Todo"}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

AddTodo.propTypes = {
  onUpdateTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  updatingTodo: PropTypes.object,
};

export default AddTodo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line where you dispatch the updateTodo action in your //Addtodo.js:

```
  dispatch(updateTodo({ id: updatingTodo, text: input }));
```

Here, you are passing the entire updatingTodo object as the id instead of just the id property. As a result, in your updateTodo reducer, when you try to access action.payload.id, it might be undefined.

To fix this, you should update the dispatch line in AddTodo.js to pass updatingTodo.id instead of the entire updatingTodo object

```
dispatch(updateTodo({ id: updatingTodo.id, text: input }));
```

so the code should look like this in your addtodohandler

```
const addTodoHandler = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
if (updatingTodo) {
dispatch(updateTodo({ id: updatingTodo.id, text: input }));
onUpdateTodo(null);
} else {
dispatch(addTodo(input));
}
setInput("");
};
```